# How to make textured planes double sided?

Tags: texturing

I'm making some grass for my game and I can't figure out how to make the planes double sided(they look fine in blender) but in Unity they are only visible on one side :/

Comment: I found a quick solution to fix this problem(I can't believe how quickly I figure it out) what you need to do is to go into the plane/model and select the shader, then go into "Particles/additive" and select "Alpha Blended" this will make your textured plane visible from both sides :)

Comment: disable backface culling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a quick solution to fix this problem(*I can't believe how quickly I figure it out*) what you need to do is to go into the plane/model and select the shader, then go into "Particles/additive" and select "Alpha Blended" this will make your textured plane visible from both sides :)
[image]